# C++ armadillo princomp() segmentation fault

Tags: c++, matrix, segmentation-fault, pca, armadillo

I'm running a code as below:

```
#define ARMA_64BIT_WORD
#include <iostream>
#include </usr/include/armadillo>
using namespace arma;
typedef Mat<float> fmat;
typedef Col<float> fvec;

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{

    fmat A;
    A.load("matrix.txt");
    fmat coeff;
    fmat score;
    fvec latent;
    fvec tsquared;

    princomp(coeff, score, latent, tsquared, A);
 return 0;
 }
```

with matrix.txt containing a 2-by-46341(2 rows, 46341 columns) matrix .
it run well, but when I increase the matrix to 2-by-46342(2 rows, 46342 columns),
a Segmentation fault (core dumped) happened.

Is there any restriction or a limit to the number of the columns ?
Or, am I writing anything wrong?

I'm running in Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-40-virtual x86_64), Menmory:16GB

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

princomp() will calculate the covariance matrix (X' * X) which in your case has size 46342x43642.  That has size 16.001 GB and you only have 16 GB.  Hence the failure.

If you compile with debugging symbols (or without -DNDEBUG or similar) then the actual memory allocation failure should be shown.

I can't recommend any other solution since I don't know what problem you're trying to solve.